# Slow motion video preview with Android MediaRecorder

Tags: android, performance, video, preview, motion

I'm trying to get **video preview** for recording in my Android application with this code:

```
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
```

The result is a video preview in **slow motion** on all devices. On some devices, the slow motion is bigger. I need a fluid preview, instead. 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, finally, with the following line:

```
 p.setRecordingHint(true);
```

Comment: can you explain what is "p" ?

Comment: it's just: Parameters p

Comment: What is the name of the parameter ?

Comment: Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();